# postgres failure: SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('interact', 'interact_id')) into iidX;

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a postgres function for reporting errors.   It uses a call to

```
SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('interact', 'interact_id')) into xxx;
```

This function is used in two ways from php.  In one, the table **interact** is accessed before the function is called.  In this case, the calls (appear to) work.  In the second case, **interact** is not used before the function is called, and the function fails with the message:

```
currval of sequence "interact_interact_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('interact', 'interact_id'))"
PL/pgSQL function "reporterror" line 5 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT reportError( 'File(bname='|| bname || ' no location data:' || SQLERRM )"
PL/pgSQL function "uploadconfirm" line 32 at PERFORM in /home/berman/public_html/gps-photo.org/php/processFile.php on line 186
```

From psql, you can see the table and a similar error message with the phrase: 'not yet defined in this session'.

```
 \dSt interact;
                                          Table "public.interact"
   Column    |            Type             |                           Modifiers                       
 webrequest  | text                        | not null
 interact_id | integer                     | not null default nextval('interact_interact_id_seq'::regclass)
 ctime       | timestamp without time zone | default now()
 uid         | integer                     | 
 successful  | boolean                     | default false
Indexes:
    "interact_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (interact_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "files" CONSTRAINT "files_interac_fk" FOREIGN KEY (interact_id) REFERENCES interact(interact_id)

pony=> SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('interact', 'interact_id')) ;
ERROR:  currval of sequence "interact_interact_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
```

I have no idea what  I am doing wrong.  Can someone help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong ;) You just have to "initialize" the sequence in each session. It is done by calling nextval(). Once you call nextval - you will be able to call currval(which will givie the value that was returned last by nextval).

[According to to the doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html):

> currval(regclass) bigint  - Return value **most recently obtained with nextval** for specified sequence

Comment: Thanks.  How do I do that?  Is there a way to test if the call to nextval is neccessary?

Comment: `select nextval('your_sequence_name') `. or more elegant `select nextval('your_sequence_name'::regclass) `. What dou you mean by necessary? In normal use of sequence, i cant imagine a situation, where I need to obtain current value before incrementing. Sequences IMHO should only be used when inserting new rows. If you want to get max value of your id field - why don't you just call `select max(id) from table` ?